# Tortoise SVN update from 1.7 to 1.8 gone wrong

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I previously had some version of TortoiseSVN 1.7 and I wanted to install a plugin for VS2012 in order to have SVN integrated, so far so good.

My problem is that after installing this plugin I was prompt to update my SVN version to 1.8 (latest). I did so, and after the installation was done I was prompt again to "Upgrade my Working Directory". I couldn't find this option anywhere in the contextual menu, so I went in the command line in the specified working dir and typed:

```
svn upgrade
```

It didn't crash, but it didn't displayed anything either, so I figured I was good to go. Now my contextual menu only has this:

[image]

And now I can't go back to having the "standard menu" with Update, Commit, ...

I've tried a brand new checkout but it won't change anything, and if I click the "SVN Upgrade working copy" button, nothing happens... everything stays the same.

I've honestly run out of idea (I've been at it all afternoon) and don't know what to try now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple instances of Subversion installed.  (Tortoise has the SVN libraries compiled in.)

From the command prompt type `svn --version` What does that show?

If you type `svn upgrade` from the command prompt what does that show?  Depending on the size of your working copy, this can take a while.

How did you check out the working copy?  It really sounds like your svn binaries are out of date and the plugin is using the latest version.

Comment: My problem was that during the install of 1.8 it didn't overwrite or uninstall 1.7... Thanks !!