# upgrading tortoise-svn-update-from-1-7-to-1-8

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My problem is identical to the one posted in [Tortoise SVN update from 1.7 to 1.8 gone wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603815/tortoise-svn-update-from-1-7-to-1-8-gone-wrong),
but I didn't find specific instructions how to resolve it

Comment: The solution is in a comment to the accepted answer there.

Comment: If you install a 1.8 plug-in to Visual Studio, you need to upgrade ALL other versions of ALL other tools (TortoiseSVN, Command line, etc.). Once the working copy has been updated to a newer version, the older tools will not work with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tortoise SVN update from 1.7 to 1.8 gone wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603815/tortoise-svn-update-from-1-7-to-1-8-gone-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

There was a change in the working directory structure between Subversion 1.7 and Subversion 1.8. It doesn't affect the repository, but it does affect using TortoiseSVN.

You may have to *upgrade* your working directory to get it to work. I don't know if you can do that in TortoiseSVN or not. Check the context menu for something that says *SVN Upgrade working copy*, or something similar.

If you can't find it, you can run it from the command line if you installed the command line client when you installed TortoiseSVN (it's an option):

```
C:\> svn upgrade
```

Once you've upgraded your working copy, you should be able to use your working directories again. Also please let us know the exact error message you're getting, and a bit more about your setup.

Also, go into the Uninstall Program control panel in Windows and make sure you don't have multiple copies of Subversion clients installed.